# Cannot resolve symbol 'dispactCommand' Error

Tags: java, minecraft

```js
package me.cvn.secondplugin.secondplugin.commands;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.ConsoleCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class nick implements Listener {

    ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender();
    Bukkit.dispatchCommand(console, "say Test");

}
```

In this script, dispatchCommand gets red format saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'dispatchCommand'" in it. I searched some but couldn't get any answer for this.

Comment: Assuming "gets red format" means your IDE is reporting a compilation error, do you have the bukkit jar on your classpath?

Comment: org.bukkit.Bukkit is working and other classes are working properly as I see.

Comment: if dispatchCommand can't be resolved, org.bukkit.Bukkit is _not_ working, unless you happen to be using some particularly old version of it that is missing this particular static method. Check the dependency version. The current is 1.16.5.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include lines in a method like this :

```java
package me.cvn.secondplugin.secondplugin.commands;

public class nick implements Listener {

   @EventHandler
   public void myListener(PlayerJoinEvent e) { // even when player join
      ConsoleCommandSender console = Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender();
      Bukkit.dispatchCommand(console, "say Test");
   }
}
```